# What word means "not straight, white, and male"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word that refers to the entire group of people who:

- identify as anything other than heterosexual OR
- racial identification is other than "white" OR
- sexual identification is anything other than male?

I would ideally find a single word, but even two words that work well to describe this.

*P.S. I would appreciate sensitivity in your answers. This isn't a place to discuss politics, merely the English language.*

*P.P.S. If there is a word that you're aware of in other languages that mean this, feel free to add as a comment; I would appreciate it.*

Comment: A quick comment on "queer": this word is very close actually, but I think it's not quite sufficient for my purpose.

Comment: *Non-normative? Minorities?*

Comment: The proletariat of Cultural Marxism

Comment: Non-males are certainly not a minority. Oppressed perhaps, but quite numerous.

Comment: Maybe "non-mainstream"?

Comment: Let your freak flag fly

Comment: **Minority LBTQ** - *minority* removes *white*, dropping the *G* removes *gay men* and straight men are not included in LBGTQ in the first place. And then maybe you coin: **MLBTQ**

Comment: Historically *disenfranchised*.

Comment: Dire straights?

Comment: @Jim Perhaps there was confusion, I *do* intend to include gay men, but I also intend to include straight women. I like the idea of trying to modify LGBTQ to include M for minority, but how do we get straight females in there. This is where I struggled.

Comment: @stevesliva This is quite good. Idk if it's exactly what I want, but close.

Comment: @BBischof - Then you can’t say “anything other than heterosexual” because straight women are heterosexual by definition.

Comment: @Jim https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction

Comment: This is English not math

Comment: @Jim I would have said AND in the case you're thinking of. This has nothing to do with math/English.

Answer (score 2):

I believe a **minority** or **minority group** is commonly used here.

See the Wikipeda page: [Minority groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minority_group).

> [**minority**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/minority) *noun* a racial, ethnic, religious, or social subdivision of a society that is subordinate to the dominant group in political, financial, or social power without regard to the size of these groups:

*Note that the size of the group does not matter in labelling it a minority. It's its social/societal power that matters*.

You can also use **marginalised group**.

Example usage:

As a reference to the group:

> Ethinic minority groups often suffer disproportionate levels of poverty.
>
> Ethinic minorities often suffer disproportionate levels of poverty.

As an individual:

> As a minority myself, I can identify with plight of the so-and-sos.
>
> As minority member myself...
>
> As a member of a minority group...
>
> We should give him extra consideration given that he's a minority.
>
> We should give him extra consideration given that he's a member of a minority group.

Comment: This was my first attempt myself, because the context that I'm using it in, these groups are minority(I am referring to novelists). However, I dislike the doubling up meaning on minority, because it suggests that I am only speaking about race(the most common dialogue in which minority is referenced). 
I like marginalized group, but I struggle with the fact that it is too general! I'm still not sure, I find that I kinda like one of the comment suggestions, so that might be my solution in the end. Thanks either way.